# Why is a successful UPDATE returning -1 rows affected?

Tags: jdbc, clojure, mariadb

I'm using

- Clojure 1.9.0
- org.clojure/java.jdbc 0.7.8
- MariaDB 10.3.9
- org.mariadb.jdbc/mariadb-java-client 2.2.6

My driver/connection string is:

```
(def db {:classname "org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver"
         :subprotocol "mariadb"
         :subname "//127.0.0.1:3306/dbname"
         :user "username"
         :password "password"})
```

I have a table `examples` with columns `comment` and `user`.

Querying works normally:

```
(jdbc/query db ["select * from examples")
;=> ({:user "existing user", :comment "example comment"})
```

The statement below successfully modifies rows in the database, but always returns `-1` in place of the number of rows affected:

```
(jdbc/execute! db ["update examples set comment = ? where user = ?"
                   "test comment"
                   "existing user"])
;=> (-1)
```

Explicitly calling `row_count()` immediately after the above returns the same result:

```
(jdbc/query db ["select row_count()"])
=> ({:row_count() -1})
```

The equivalent commands give the correct results in the mariadb ("`mysql`") shell.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Something to do with this maybe? https://github.com/MariaDB/mariadb-connector-j/blob/caad0f1682062251595978a454a37b50a3515c40/src/main/java/org/mariadb/jdbc/MariaDbStatement.java#L1015

Comment: Maybe it's related to [No method returns update counts in batch mode](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/CONJ-630).